# How to sort Array with own key in python

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort the array a with the function countPixel.
But with a array len bigger then one ive got the error:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
def countPixel(e):
    if(e[2] - e[0] > e[3] - e[1]):
        return (e[2] - e[0]) * (e[3] - e[1])

boxesKoar = [[492, 592, 1122, 772], [1308, 558, 1416, 832], [1740, 633, 1872, 727]]
print(boxesKoar)
boxesKoar.sort(key = countPixel, reverse = True)
print(boxesKoar)
```

Comment: If this `(e[2] - e[0] > e[3] - e[1])` is False you are going to return `None`, what do you want to do case this is False?

Answer (score 1):

In python language function implicitly `return None`, so

```
def countPixel(e):
    if(e[2] - e[0] > e[3] - e[1]):
        return (e[2] - e[0]) * (e[3] - e[1])
```

if written more explicitly would be:

```
def countPixel(e):
    if(e[2] - e[0] > e[3] - e[1]):
        return (e[2] - e[0]) * (e[3] - e[1])
    return None
```

You need to rework your function so it would always return object supporting `<` comparison, as [HOWTO: sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) states

```
The sort routines are guaranteed to use __lt__() when making comparisons between two objects.
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: @gregmasterst Yes, because your function `countPixels` returns `None` in some cases. It should never return `None`. What do you want `countPixels` to return if `(e[2] - e[0] <= e[3] - e[1])` ? Should it be 0 ? Should it be some other value? You need to explicitly add `else: return (something)`  in that function.